# Markov algorithm: pick rule first, then position, or the other way around?

Tags: terminology, computation-models, didactics

A Markov algorithm is a string rewriting system (well, not a set of rules but a list of rules since they need to be ordered) with a strategy for applying rules that ensures determinism.

I think the usual definition (1) is

> Find the first rule that matches, and then replace its leftmost occurence.

Another definition (2) could be

> Find the leftmost position where any rule matches, and then apply the first of the matching rules.

Does it matter? I think both should be equivalent w.r.t. the set of functions computed.

Which one is more economical for teaching?

E.g., for a simulation by a Turing machine, (2) seems better - less movements of the head, we can scan the tape once, by a finite automaton. But we need to "overscan" in case the left-hand sides of rules are not prefix-free. (Well this low-level programming is a mess any way you put it.)

Simulation of Turing machine by Markov algorithm is not a problem since we can build the rules in such a way that there is at most one match (when starting from an initial configuration), so the strategy does not matter.

Comment: What do you mean by "more economical"? What is the main question here; the one about equivalence or the one about didactics?

Comment: didactics (there was a line in italics  in my original version, but it has been edited away)

Comment: In that case, please explain what you mean by "economical" and give objective criteria. (This platform is ill-suited for collecting opinions.)

Comment: I think this question can be saved, but it needs a lot of work. For starters: have you tried to find a counterexample to your assumption ("I think both should be equivalent w.r.t. the set of functions computed")? Also: your final observations are not helpful in *defining* the second question (whose answer depends on finding an answer to the first, mind you), so consider leaving it aside, for now.

Comment: Sure I can prove the equivalence but I won't do it here (I may want put this as a homework problem). - "economical": not wasting any ressources, and a teacher should know what these are (time in the lecture, space on theblackboard, attention of students, etc.)

Comment: Have you *effectively* proved? It is necessary, you know. And, if so, why are you asking?